# Appium Java JUNIT - "We could not find a *-tests.jar file" - AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, automation, appium, aws-device-farm

I'm trying to upload an automation scenarion to AWS,and I'm having an issue currently. tests.jar file is not available for me even if I unzip the test file. What should I do next?

The only solution they mentioned is to unzip and verify that the file exist,but I can't find him. Hope to hear from you

[image: error image]

Comment: Would you be able to share you pom.xml file?  It should look like this doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-java-junit.html#test-types-android-appium-java-junit-prepare 

You can build the project using: 
mvn clean package -DskipTests=true

Comment: pom.xml file: https://gist.github.com/nirkalsi/0d7d2c9d349ad21df1734f780c8f00ef

Answer (score 0):

I built a sample junit test using these commands:

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

with an artifact id of testofjunit.

Then I copied most of the pom contents from [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-device-farm-appium-tests-for-sample-app) with the zip.xml for the assembly file. The project now looked like this after running `mvn clean package -DskipTests=true`:

```
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   ├───assembly
│   │   └───java
│   │       └───com
│   │           └───stackoverflow
│   │               └───www
│   └───test
│       └───java
│           └───com
│               └───stackoverflow
│                   └───www
└───target
    ├───archive-tmp
    ├───classes
    │   └───com
    │       └───stackoverflow
    │           └───www
    ├───dependency-jars
    ├───generated-sources
    │   └───annotations
    ├───generated-test-sources
    │   └───test-annotations
    ├───maven-archiver
    ├───maven-status
    │   └───maven-compiler-plugin
    │       ├───compile
    │       │   └───default-compile
    │       └───testCompile
    │           └───default-testCompile
    └───test-classes
        └───com
            └───stackoverflow
                └───www
```

This created a zip-with-dependencies.zip file in the `./target` directory. Uploading that to Devic Farm passed the parser.

[image: parse success]

Would you be able to let me know if we're uploading th zip file or the jar? Device Farm is expecting a zip file to be uploaded.

HTH

James